# How to convert c code to vb.net?

Tags: c, vb.net

How can I convert the following into VB? What does it mean?

```
unsigned char *s = (unsigned char *)(void *)serialNum;
```

Comment: Something like

    `Dim s As String
    Dim serialNum As String

    serialNum := "123A456Z"
    s := serialNum`

Share and enjoy.

Comment: What is the type of `serialNum`?

Comment: Here is teh function name for the code i am after long init_Function21(char *serialNum, int sequence, char *table)

Comment: Give us some context. The type of serialNum would be nice, as well as what is done with it afterwards and how it gets it's value. At the moment, this looks like an example of unhelpful undefined behaviour and the question will likely get closed without further context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what little I know about VB, I'm not sure there is a translation.

It looks like the intent of the code is to take an integer value (`serialNum`) and use it as the *address* of a sequence of bytes (`s`).

`unsigned char *s` declares `s` to be a pointer to `unsigned char`; the value stored in `s` is the *address* of a single byte or the first byte of a sequence.

`(unsigned char *)` and `(void *)` are *cast operations*; they are used to convert the type of an expression to a different type.  C's type rules are such that you cannot assign an integer value to a pointer variable directly; the integer value must be converted to a pointer type using a cast operation.  `(void *) serialNum` converts the type of the expression `serialNum` from `int` (or whatever) to `void *`, which is C's idea of a "generic" pointer.  `(unsigned char *)` converts the result of the previous expression to pointer to `unsigned char`.

The `(void *)` cast operation is redundant IMO, and the following should work just as well:

```
unsigned char *s = (unsigned char *) serialNum;
```

Again, I don't know what an appropriate translation in VB would be.

Comment: following line simple resolved my problem : Dim s As String = serialNum. And for pointer position i used array to save the whole string and loop through. Obviously used business logic to encrypt the serialnumber using bitwise operators (can share business logic due to clients security policy). hope this is helpful for all the readers.

Comment: I changed the above line of code to Dim s As String = serialNum. and it resolved the issue. Thank you all...

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to tell from the context. Presumably `serialNum` is an un-typed (`void *` in C) pointer.

The pointer value is copied into `s`, which has the type "pointer to unsigned character".

The code looks as if someone has built a string in `serialNum`, but the pointer is shared in an un-typed manner, so the receiver needs to know that it should be treated as `unsigned char *`.